# Events of multiple cells in single column

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gwt-celltable

I have two buttons(edit + delete) in one column.

```
    ButtonCell functionButtonCell = new ButtonCell() {
    @Override
    public void render(final Context context, final SafeHtml data, final SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("<button type='button' class='gwt-Button' style = 'width:60px;margin:1px;'>Edit</button>");
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("<br/>");
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("<button type='button' class='gwt-Button' style = 'width:60px;margin:1px;'>Delete</button>");
        }
    };
    functionColumn = new Column<AdminModel, String>(functionButtonCell) {
        public String getValue(final AdminModel object) {
            return object.getSeq().toString();
        }
    };
```

Bind event for this column in Presenter as

```
.........
view.getFunctionColumn().setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<AdminModel, String>() {

   public void update(final int index, final AdminModel object, final String value) {
            Window.alert(index + "-" + value);
        }
    });
```

After clicked on *edit button* , alert-box has appeared , but not on *delete button*. When I clicked on *delete button* , nothing has appeared. What would be the problem ?

> **Addition:** *How can I decide which button was clicked by user (edit or delete) from my presenter ?*

I would really appreciate any of your suggestions because I am troubled on it for a long times. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ButtonCell` filters events on the first child element only: https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.6.1/user/src/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ButtonCell.java This is why you don't get an event when clicking the second button (note: the goal of that code is to make sure you clicked on the button, and not on blank space around the button; see https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/a0dc88c8be7408be9554f746eb1ec93798183a28)

The easiest way to implement a two-button cell is to use a [`CompositeCell`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/CompositeCell.html); it requires that child cells are rendered into sibling elements though (uses `<span>`s by default, example below overrides the rendering to use `<div>`s so your buttons stack each on its own line).

```
new CompositeCell<AdminModel>(Arrays.asList(
  // First button
  new HasCell<AdminModel, String>() {
    @Override public Cell<String> getCell() { return new ButtonCell(); }
    @Override public FieldUpdated<AdminModel, String> getFieldUpdater() {
      return new FieldUpdater<AdminModel, String>() {
        @Override public void update(int index, AdminModel object, String value) {
          Window.alert("Edit " + object.getId());
        }
      };
    }
    @Override public String getValue(AdminModel o) {
      return "Edit";
    }
  },
  // Second button
  new HasCell<AdminModel, String>() {
    @Override public Cell<String> getCell() { return new ButtonCell(); }
    @Override public FieldUpdated<AdminModel, String> getFieldUpdater() {
      return new FieldUpdater<AdminModel, String>() {
        @Override public void update(int index, AdminModel object, String value) {
          Window.alert("Delete " + object.getId());
        }
      };
    }
    @Override public String getValue(AdminModel o) {
      return "Delete";
    }
  }) {
  @Override protected <X> void render(Cell.Context context, AdminModel value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb, HasCell<String,X> hasCell) {
    // use a <div> instead of the default <span>
    Cell<X> cell = hasCell.getCell();
    sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div>");
    cell.render(context, hasCell.getValue(value), sb);
    sb.appendHtmlConstant("</div>");
  }
};
```

(note: in your case, because the button's text doesn't depend on the row object, maybe you should rather use an `ActionCell`; it would better fit "semantically" with what you're doing, but otherwise it's almost the same; with an `ActionCell`, you'd use `HasCell<AdminModel, AdminModel>`, `ActionCell<AdminModel>`, `getFieldUpdater` would return `null, and the`getValue`of the`HasCell`would just return the`AdminModel` argument as-is).

Otherwise, implement your `Cell` (or `AbstractCell`) entirely by yourself.

Comment: Sir ! Now I got as I want. But when click on button I got error as [----this----](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396252/gwt-handling-event-in-composite-cell) question mentioned. And as you answer on that question , gwt 2.5 may fix. But I am also using gwt 2.5 and still getting error. Any suggestions sir ?

Comment: Error is *com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) @com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl::apply(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)([JavaScript object(1064), JavaScript object(645), JavaScript object(1220)]): elem is null*

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, a column should have only one type of cell be it `ImageCell`, `ButtonCell` etc. Because all this `ImageCell` and `ButtonCell` does not provide any in-built events. The events are handled by `FieldUpdater` itself which does not have differentiators to identify that which `ButtonCell` is clicked. Ideally on click of that column, the field-updater will be called.

You should rather create your own composite widget which extends `HasCell`. This composite widget will have two different buttons and those in built methods are called on click of respective button.

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    CellTable<Person> table = new CellTable<Person>();

    List<HasCell<Person, ?>> cells = new LinkedList<HasCell<Person, ?>>();
    cells.add(new ActionHasCell("Edit", new Delegate<Person>() {

        @Override
        public void execute(Person object) {
           // EDIT CODE
        }
    }));
    cells.add(new ActionHasCell("Delete", new Delegate<Person>() {

        @Override
        public void execute(Person object) {
            // DELETE CODE
        }
    }));

    CompositeCell<Person> cell = new CompositeCell<Person>(cells);
    table.addColumn(new TextColumn<Person>() {

        @Override
        public String getValue(Person object) {
            return object.getName()
        }
    }, "Name");

    // ADD Cells for Age and Address

    table.addColumn(new Column<Person, Person>(cell) {

        @Override
        public Person getValue(Person object) {
            return object;
        }
    }, "Actions");


}

private class ActionHasCell implements HasCell<Person, Person> {
    private ActionCell<Person> cell;

    public ActionHasCell(String text, Delegate<Person> delegate) {
        cell = new ActionCell<Person>(text, delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public Cell<Person> getCell() {
        return cell;
    }

    @Override
    public FieldUpdater<Person, Person> getFieldUpdater() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Person getValue(Person object) {
        return object;
    }
}
```

Also, see the link below. 
[[GWT CellTable-Need to have two buttons in last single cell of each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108317/gwt-celltable-need-to-have-two-buttons-in-last-single-cell-of-each-row][1])

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir ! And ... pls support me usage of it. Am I need to create new Composite Class ? How to add this to my cellTable ?

Comment: @Cataclysm : ActionHasCell is the composite widget created and being utilized in the onModuleLoad() for CellTable. Try to understand the implementation provided.

Comment: Please don't be mind sir , I didn't catch yet. I am still a newbie on GWT. So , I would like to know how to create my column with compoisite class that you described. Thanks.